# Replacing a standard 120v outlet with new outlet with USB charging

Tags: electrical

I want to replace a standard 120v outlet. It has a copper ground, and on the left side a white wire to the top silver screw, and on the right side 2 black wires (one to each brass screw). My new outlet (duplex receptacle and 2 USB charging points) only has a ground screw, a silver terminal screw, and a brass terminal screw. Where do I attach the extra black wire?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add a pic or 2 of your existing wiring.

Comment: One problem is that most circuits have one black with/paired with one white.  On the side with the blacks, is the tab connecting the two screws there or broken off?  Two blacks and one white is usually not good.

Comment: Is there a light switch on the wall of the room? If so, does it control any lights? On the old receptacle, do both top and bottom outlets work?

Comment: The only switch is for the overhead lights (3 way switch). I put an outlet tester in each outlet and flipped every switch in the house - each outlet stayed "hot" for every switch. There is one outlet in the dining room that is switched; the outlet is installed with the ground slot "up", and all other outlets are installed with ground slot down. I did check, and that switch does not control my outlet in question.

Comment: First, a safety question -- I presume you are doing all this mucking around in the box with all power verified OFF by turning off the circuit breaker(s) involved, and checking all possible combos of each black, the white, and the ground for 0 voltage -- right? With that, do the two black wires and one white all come from the same cable? Also your two blacks are whites remarked as black, which is unusual at best. Are there any actual black wires in the box? Can you post a picture of the inside of the box showing the connections in there clearly?

Comment: There are cables that come into the box - each has a black, a white, and a ground. The whites are connected with a wire nut, and a jumper comes out of the nut and attaches to the silver screw. The black wires attach directly to the brass screws. The copper grounds are connected with a wire nut and a jumper attaches to the outlet. I initially thought that there were white wires  marked as black, but it appears when the house was built the painters sprayed right over the wires. When I look at the wires where they enter the box, they are the appropriate colors.

Comment: Also, assuming you have turned the power off to do this work, does one single breaker handle turn off all the power to both halves of the outlet? Or do you have to turn off two breakers, one for each half? If it's two breakers are they next to each other with the handles linked together, or are they separate?

Comment: One breaker turns off the whole outlet (as well as all my kitchen lights). Once I get this figured out, I will turn the breaker off before switching out the outlets during daylight hours. Also, on my previous comment it should say "2 cables that come into the box".

Comment: I just want to confirm what you're saying because it's a bit unusual. You have a single outlet split in two, which we can see because the little tab is removed on the hot (black) side, and there are two hot wires connected. Both parts can be turned off by a single breaker with a single handle, and *neither part is controlled by a switch*. What you have is normal for a switched receptacle but not for an unswitched one. Are there any switches in the same room that don't seem to control anything? While we're at it, which room of the house is this receptacle in?

Comment: This outlet is above the built-in desk in the kitchen. There is a phone jack 6 inches to the left of it. There are NO switches that don't appear to control anything. I checked every switch in the house, even the bedroom switches. The house was built in 2006. There is a switched outlet in the dining room area, one in the master bedroom, and one in the guest bedroom. The switched outlets are installed "upside down".

Comment: Thanks for all the details. That's fairly odd. It sounds like maybe they originally wired this to be a switched receptacle and then didn’t switch it. But the fact that it is in the kitchen raises another question -- is it within 6' of a sink, or on a countertop? Kind of doubting that from your description, but worth checking. If so GFCI protection is required (and was when the house was built).

Comment: It's not close to a sink or counter top. The previous owner had a telephone plugged into it. Am I OK to use either of the black wires and the white and ground wires for my new outlet, and cap the remaining black wire with a wire nut?

Comment: I would suggest that you _NOT_ replace this with a USB charging outlet. Power demands for devices has been rapidly increasing, and this outlet may power the devices you have now, but not the ones you have next year. The wall wart that comes with next year's device will plug into any standard 120v outlet for decades to come and will provide the necessary power. You'll be "upgrading" your USB receptacles every year or two trying to keep up...

Comment: Looking closely at the picture I think that the tab is *not* broken off on the hot side. My guess would be that one of the wires is sending power to an outlet further down the line, and that for some reason the neutral for that later outlet is joined with a wire nut or something instead of also being attached to the outlet. If that's the case then you just have to do the same thing on the hot side, join the two hot wires together with a pigtail to the new outlet.

Comment: @FreeMan eh, is it really worse to upgrade a USB receptable than to upgrade a USB wall wart? Less convenient, certainly, but to some people, having the wall wart is also inconvenient. As I see it the main downside is when someone who doesn't know you can replace outlets has a problem with it.

Comment: @user253751 the wall wart will come with the device and provide whatever power the device needs. A USB outlet from 3-5 years ago would only provide 500-1000mA which wouldn't even come close to charging many new devices today. Also, form factor changes. A USB-C cable won't fit into a USB 1/2/3 port, but it'll fit into the port on the wart included with the device.

Comment: One of the major problems with USB ports integrated with 120V outlets is that they *typically* are designed to older USB charging specifications and *won't* provide as fast charging as the USB adapter provided with a current generation phone. For charging, almost any USB port will, mostly, work, but the rate of charging will *not* be equivalent. USB charging has become a complex issue. To know what you're getting, you *must* look in detail at the specifications of the USB port/charger.

Comment: *Lots* of lower-end chargers will do their best in their marketing images/text to make it look like they will perform at a higher capability level than what they will actually perform. It's *possible* for an integrated 120V outlet + USB charging to provide the same or better capabilities as a current generation charger. However, that capability is notably more expensive/complex (variable voltage/current) than the baseline USB charging capability (just a straight +5V supply).

Comment: Just a warning. USB charging standards were updated at least 4 times since I last changed my outlets. If I had installed outlets with USB, as I planned, it would already be unusable, sitting there, leeching small amounts of miliampers, when I use newer charging bricks anyway. Are you sure it's worth it?

Comment: In addition to all the comments about the value of USB receptacles (good points there), what @2012rcampion said is important. Take a look at this picture of the tab that connects the two halves of a receptacle: https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/2016-11-15_0001-1-650x301.jpg . Is that little tab broken off, or present, on the hot (black wires) side of the receptacle in question? A lot of the previous comments, including mine, assumed it was broken off. If it's present that's a very different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 11):

If you look at the silver screw side of the receptacle you'll see a small metal tab in the notch near the face of the receptacle that joins the two screw baseplates. That tab has been broken off on the brass screw side shown in you picture in order to separate the two halves of the receptacle into separate circuits. The typical application is to control one half of the outlet with a switch while the other half is always live. (Both halves might be switched independently.)

You have a choice of making the new outlet always on or switched, simply pick the appropriate black wire to supply power and insulate the remaining black wire with a suitable wire nut.

Comment: The catch is that if the switch controlling the half-receptacle does not control anything else then you have removed the *required* switched light capability. So that needs to be figured out first.

Comment: I would like to make my new outlet "always on" (no other option with only a silver and a brass screw). I can find no switch that controls either half of the existing outlet, both have power to them. What is the best way to determine which black wire to use?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact true if there are no permanent lighting fixtures installed. But if there are switched ceiling lights or similar then you don't have to have a switched receptacle.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably switched outlet.

A switch will control one of the plugs.

You have the option of leaving it as is (switchable outlet) by breaking up the small connector on the side of the plugs and connect the two blacks to each of the screws, while keeping the white on the other side.

You can also connect one white and one black and cap off the other black or connect the 2 blacks under one screw.

Comment: I don't need a switched outlet there (I have no extra switches, so not sure where it would be controlled). Also, with my new outlet I can't keep it wired the same - I only have one silver screw and one brass screw (and the ground screw of course).